# Rails: How to set custom key on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

I have two models: `ActivityFeed (:id, :activity_id,...)` and `ActivityTour (:activity_id, :tour_id)`.

```
class ActivityFeed < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :activity_tours, foreign_key: :activity_id
end

class ActivityTour < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :activity_feed, foreign_key: :activity_id
end
```

I have create two records like: `a = ActivityFeed.create(activity_id: 123,..)` and `b = ActivityTour.create(activity_id: 123,..)`.

I expected `b.activity_feed` would return `a` but it returns `nil` instead.

This is the query `SELECT  "activity_feeds".* FROM "activity_feeds" WHERE "activity_feeds"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 123], ["LIMIT", 1]]`.

Please tell me what I need to fix this. I would be very appreciate

Comment: You gotta pass in the activity_feed_id when you create the activity tour record. Ie something like this:  `b = ActivityTour.create(activity_feed_id: a.id)` add in the other attributes as appropriate of course!

Comment: yup and also set the foreign key properly as the other answers below say

Comment: thanks @BKSpurgeon, I could change the column name to `activity_feed_id` but it's strictly to use `activity_id` in this case. I tried as @Tai suggest and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to create association as below:

```
class ActivityFeed < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activity_tours, foreign_key: :activity_id, primary_key: :activity_id
end

class ActivityTour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity_feed, foreign_key: :activity_id, primary_key: :activity_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is vague for active record to distinguish between `activity_id` in `ActivityFeed` and `ActivityTour` when you set it as `foreign_key`. So, it's suitable to change `ActivityTour` structure into `ActivityTour (:activity_feed_id, :tour_id)`. Then define associations as bellow:

```
   class ActivityFeed < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :activity_tours, foreign_key: :activity_feed_id
   end

   class ActivityTour < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :activity_feed, foreign_key: :activity_feed_id
   end
```